# Automatically finding server on local network from Android app

Tags: java, android, rest, network-programming

I am working on a system consisting of a server and an Android app, which has to contact said server. In the app, it is currently possible to specify the server address, but we now want the client to automatically look for the server on the local network to make it more usable. My current understanding of the problem is that I can send a message to the local broadcast address at `255.255.255.255`, and then this message will reach all IP's in the local network. So far, I came up with the following:

```
try {
    DatagramSocket discoveryBroadcaster = new DatagramSocket();
    discoveryBroadcaster.send(new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(),msg.getBytes().length,
            InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"),8000));
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

We communicate with the server through a RESTful interface. I would like the message we send to be a GET request so that we can implement the response on the server as an endpoint just like everything else. The problem is that the only way I know of to create a GET request is through the `httpurlconnection` class, which needs a target URL first. Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to compose a GET request as a string and then send it to the broadcast address?
2. Will sending a GET request to the broadcast address work?
3. Is the above a correct or viable approach to solving this problem?

Comment: `I can send a message to the local broadcast address ` I? Who would send that message? And what would be the message?

Comment: `We communicate with the server through a RESTful interface`. What has your server to do with this? Or how clients communicate with the server?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to send with a querystring as GET request. Give an example of content please.

Comment: 1. The client would send such a message using the `DatagramSocket` as shown in the code fragment.2

Comment: 2. The RESTful interface has to do with this because we would like to have all communication to the server to be RESTful, including the discovery requests if this is possible.

Comment: 3. We want to send a simple get request to an endpoint on the server, at [server-ip]/isAvailable for example, so the server can respond to the message which was broadcast with a payload containing its IP. The client then knows where the server is located.

Comment: You should let the server broadcast its ip to begin with. That is the normal approach using UDP. Not even the server should do this but a different application that runs on the same pc as the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to solve you problem is to make both server and android app follow [Zeroconf protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking).

After configuring one of implementations on server and in android app you will get IP address of server which you are looking for. Then you will be able to send *http* requests as usual.

Here is some good article about [using Zeroconf in android](https://medium.com/@_tiwiz/bonjour-android-its-zeroconf-8e3d3fde760e).

Answer (score 1):

more information about Zeroconf, it's called Network Service Discovery in Android

your server broadcast the service and the android devices listen to the service:

https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html